# Shell Scripting For loop Syntax Error

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to make a simple shell script to ping a source but I am getting

```
bash-2.03$ ./test.sh google.com 10 .5 /home/users/me 16 256
./test.sh: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `(('
./test.sh: line 35: `for (( i = 1 ; i <= $totalArguments ; i++ ))'
```

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=$1
count=$2
interval=$3
outputDirectory=$4
shift;
shift;
shift;
shift;
totalArguments=$#

for (( i = 1 ; i <= $totalArguments ; i++ ))
do 
    ping -c $count -i $interval -s ${!i} $ip >> $outputDirectory/${!i}results.txt
done
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with the for loop syntax?
Thanks!

Comment: the for loop syntax looks fine.

Comment: Script works as is for me on bash version 3.2.49.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [CHANGES](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) file, that style of `for` loop was added in Bash 2.04.

You will need to use [`seq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq):

```
for i in $(seq $totalArguments)
```